# Confusion in the prior requirements of Moment Inequalities

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

Why is the function required to be monotonic here? I understand if the function is not monotonic the first equality would not hold true. But the second inequality will always hold true with respect to the first probability i.e

$$P(|X - \mu| \geq t) \leq \frac{E[f(|X-\mu|)]}{f(t)}$$

Did I do some mistake in my calculation? Elaboration of this slide would be nice.

[image]

Comment: Is  the first equality true for strictly monotonic _decreasing_ functions?

Comment: @kimchilover Huh! you are right I guess....didn't see that